# Magento Cleaning Log feature doesn't work

Tags: magento, logging, cron

I'd like to find the problem with my Cleaning Log feature.
I'm using Magento 1.7 and have magento's cron working(already checked in database - cron_schedule) by cron.sh.

The problem: my log tables are still full after I enable the Cleaning Log and I'm not seeing anything related with in the cron_schedule table!

My System > Configuration > System

```
CRON(SCHEDULE TASK)

Generate Schedules Every 60
Schedule Ahead for 1
Missed if Not Run Within 60
History Cleanup Every 120
Success History Lifetime 120
Failure History Lifetime 120
============================
LOG CLEANING

Save Log, Days 1
Enable Log Cleaning YES
Start Time 00:30:00
Frequency DAILY
Error Email Recipient MYEMAIL@BLABLA.COM
Error Email Sender GENERAL CONTACT
Error Email Template LOG CLEANUP WARNING
```

One important thing(the hardest part): I need to fix that without the Community Maintenance Script or any solution not built-in.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you enable cron logging, so you can actually see the error log of crontab itself?:: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Comment: Hi Cninroh, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately the log from crontab is a 0KB file...

Answer (score 1):

1. If your cron is set and crontab setting are set as per frequencies then logs should be cleaned.
2. My thoughts are that due to some error. Generally timeout or memory errors your cron is not able to complete its execution.
   Ss check your logs and var reports if any exceptin due to cron.

Comment: Well, what I'm not understanding is why the command to clean up the tables isn't been set on 'cron_schedule'. The rest of the crontabs are all there. Logs checked and no cron's message.

Comment: the Magneto system has a built-in for cleaning up log information. If you go to

System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Log Cleaning

You can configure your store to automatically clean up these logs.

Comment: For me is written "Cron (Scheduled Tasks) - all the times are in minutes" so I figured out those values would be in minutes

Comment: And the "Save Log, Days" is set 1

Answer (score 0):

The relations between log DB tables could be broken (e.g. after manually cleaning). If you suspect a problem might be there then try to check your DB:

If DB query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log_url LEFT JOIN log_visitor ON (log_url.visitor_id = log_visitor.visitor_id) WHERE log_visitor.visitor_id IS NULL
```

returns a positive number, then there are some log records that are not relates to any visitor. Those records never removed by log cleaning. In that case execute

```
DELETE FROM log_url WHERE visitor_id NOT IN (SELECT visitor_id FROM log_visitor)
```

After that execute cleaning log again. In console terminal execute

```
php -f shell/log.php -- clean --days X
```

where X is day limit. It could be help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the cleaner depends on information in log_ tables to be related to report_event so it doesn't just do a delete from across every table, something like this:

```
sendto(4, "\370\0\0\0\3SELECT `event_table`.`event_id` FROM `report_event` AS `event_table`\n LEFT JOIN `log_visitor` AS `visitor_table` ON event_table.subject_id = visitor_table.visitor_id WHERE (visitor_table.visitor_id IS NULL) AND (event_table.subtype = 1) LIMIT 1000", 252, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 252
sendto(4, "{\2\0\0\3DELETE FROM `report_event` WHERE (event_id IN('39848474', '39848475', '39848476', '39848477', '39848478', '39848479', '39848480', '39848481', '39848482', '39848483', '39848484', '39848485', '39848486', '39848487', '39848488', '39848489', '39848490', '39848491', '39848492', '39848493', '39848494', '39848495', '39848496', '39848497', '39848498', '39848499', '39848500', '39848501', '39848502', '39848503', '39848504', '39848505', '39848506', '39848507', '39848508', '39848509', '39848510', '39848511', '39848512', '39848513', '39848514', '39848515', '39848516', '39848517', '39848518', '39848519', '39848520', '39848521', '39848522'))", 639, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, 0) = 639
```

So if there isn't a corresponding row in the log_ tables you can see report_event slowly inflate.